# The usual metric on $\mathbb N$ is equivalent to the discrete metric, and any metric on a finite set is equivalent to the discrete metric

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Show that the usual metric on $\mathbb N$ is equivalent to the discrete metric, and any metric on a *finite* set is equivalent to the discrete metric.

First of all, two metrics $d,\rho$ are equivalent if they generate the same convergent sequences, i.e. $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ iff $\rho(x_n,x)\to 0$.

The usual metric on $\mathbb N$ is the one it inherits from $\mathbb R$. Let's denote this metric by $d$, and the discrete metric by $d_0$. My proof is as follows:
$[\Rightarrow]$ Let $d(x_n,x) \to 0$, i.e. $|x_n-x| \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. In $\epsilon$ notation, $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N\ \forall n\ge N (|x_n - x| < \epsilon)$$
Take $\epsilon = 1$, and find suitable $N$. For all $n\ge N$, we have no choice but $x_n = x$. This is immediate from the fact that $x_n$ is a sequence on $\mathbb N$. $x_n$ is thus, eventually constant. This tells us that $d_0(x_n,x) = 0$ for $n\ge N$. We conclude $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N\ \forall n\ge N (d_0(x_n,x) < \epsilon)$$
because no matter what $\epsilon$, we can always just pick $N$ as the same one picked above to get $d_0(x_n,x) = 0$.

$[\Leftarrow]$ Let $d_0(x_n,x)\to 0$. So, $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N\ \forall n\ge N (d_0(x_n,x) < \epsilon)$$
Take $\epsilon = 1$, and find suitable $N$. For $n\ge N$, we have $d_0(x_n,x) = 0$ so $x_n = x$, i.e. $x_n$ is eventually constant. It is easy to see that $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N\in\mathbb N\ \forall n\ge N (|x_n - x| < \epsilon)$$ holds, since for whatever $\epsilon$ we have, we can always choose $N$ as the same one we chose in the previous step. The proof ends here.

**Question 1:** Is the above proof alright?

**Question 2:** I have no clue how to begin the second half, i.e. **any metric** on a **finite** set is equivalent to the discrete metric. How do I do this? It is a really strong statement!

Thanks a lot for your help and attention.

P.S. A follow-up question:
If $M$ is a countable set and $d$ is a metric on $M$, then is $d$ equivalent to the discrete metric on $M$?

Comment: You've defined "equivalent metrics" in terms of convergence of sequences, which for metric topologies amounts to getting the same topology.  A different (stronger) condition is often attached to "equivalent metries", but with your definition in place you are starting well.  One of the properties of a metric will immediately give you the discrete topology on any finite set.

Comment: For question 2, because the set (call it $A$) is finite, so is $A\times A$. Thus there are only finitely many values that $d(x,y) : A\times A \to \Bbb R$ can take on. For your follow up question, consider $$\left\{\frac 1{n+1}\;\middle|\; n \in \Bbb N\right\} \cup \{0\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1.** The proof looks correct to me.

---

**Answer 2.** The idea is the same. (A sequence converges in the discrete metric iff it is eventually constant.)

Let $A = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ be a finite set and let $d_0$ be a metric on $A$. Consider $$r = \min_{1 \le i < j \le n}d(a_i, a_j).$$
The $\min$ makes sense because it is over a finite set. Moreover, $r > 0$. (I am assuming that the listed quantities are distinct.)

Now, can you imitate your proof of part 1 to show that convergent sequences in $(A, d)$ are eventually constant? (Note that $\epsilon = 1$ was super useful there for some reason. Can $\epsilon = r$ fulfil the same purpose here?)

As earlier, can you now conclude that $d$ must be equivalent to the discrete metric?

---

For the follow-up: Consider the countable set $\Bbb Q$ with the standard metric. Note that $\dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$ in this metric. Is the same true in the discrete metric?